# NSOperationQueue ....unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, addressbook, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to implement a contact app.

In the MyContactsViewController, I am trying to get access to Contacts and if the access is granted I will fetch the contacts from my address book. The `ContactHandler` is my model class(singleton) which has the method called `getAllContacts` to get the contacts in a NSMutableArray.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    contactHandler = [ContactHandler sharedInstance];
    if(!self.accessGranted){
        NSOperationQueue *queue =[[ NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        [queue performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getAccessToAddressBook) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
        contactList = [contactHandler getAllContacts];
    }
    else{
        contactList = [contactHandler getAllContacts];
    }

}

-(BOOL)getAccessToAddressBook{

    CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    if( [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts] == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){

        [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if(granted){
                self.accessGranted = YES;
            }
            else{
                self.accessGranted = NO;
            }
        }];
    }
    else if( [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts]== CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){
        self.accessGranted = YES;
    }
    else{
        self.accessGranted = NO;
    }
    return self.accessGranted;
}
```

But I am getting this error -

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSOperationQueue getAccessToAddressBook]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137630700'
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: `[queue performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getAccessToAddressBook) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];` What do you want to do exactly? That's the line causing the issue.

Comment: By pressing cmd+click, does it go to the method ? Also try to waitUntilDone:NO

Comment: I am  trying to get the permission before I go to fetch the contacts. Basically I want to call the getAllContacts method after I get response from the getAccessToAddressBook method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
[queue performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getAccessToAddressBook) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
```

You're asking `queue` to perform `getAccessToAddressBook` when is `self` who has this selector

If you want to run the method `getAccessToAddressBook` on the queue, you can use [- addOperationWithBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperationWithBlock:)

Answer (score 0):

As in this line: `performSelectorOnMainThread` you are passing `withObject:self`, where as in method definition i.e `(BOOL)getAccessToAddressBook`you are not using it, which is causing the crash, so make `withObject:nil` , if you don't want to pass any object or value to the method.

Change this line:-

```
 [queue performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getAccessToAddressBook) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
```

to this:-

```
 [queue performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getAccessToAddressBook) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

**Or the better approach will be to write like this:-**

```
   NSOperationQueue *opQueue=[NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getAccessToAddressBook) object:nil];
 [opQueue addOperation:op ];
```

Comment: I changed it to nil but it is still giving me the same error.